# How do you keep your Javascript libraries updated to the latest versions in a large web project?

Tags: jquery, javascript

When working on a larger web project (say 20 plus pages), how do you keep your Javascript libraries updated to the latest versions?  I specifically use jQquery a lot.  It seems like everytime I look, there is a new version out.  I include the jQuery library on all my pages and it's a pain to have to update it on each page.  What do other people do?  I'm sure a big answer will be to use a framework with a single front controller.  And I have considered that, but I'm not ready to go that route yet.

Comment: Are you using plain html or any page processor like php?

Comment: If you don't want a include system or front controller, then your best bet is to keep updating it manually. To make things easier you could use a tool that supports Find/Replace in files like Notepad++.

Comment: I do use PHP, so I'd be up for some sort of "include" option.  Could someone give me an example of what that would look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### We don't.

It might automatically break things when an update is not backwards compatible. We check the mailing lists and forums regularly too check if new versions have come out, read the changelog and/or codediff, and check our plugins for compatibility. We usually clone the server to a goldencoat, test the new version there and see if anything breaks.

**If the advantages outweigh the effort needed** for the update, we do so, but only after enough time has passed and the version's initial bugs have been found and solved by the community.

Comment: Using outdated JavaScript libraries is often [a significant security risk](https://snyk.io/blog/known-vulnerabilities-in-javascript/), so it is important to update these libraries when vulnerabilities are found.

Comment: Hi, I've checked your link (and the links on that page) but it isn't clear to me what they mean by "vulnerability". Usually one would have to weigh the seriousness/impact of a vulnerability against the cost of upgrading - if it's just a memory leak or a "might confuse users", that's different than "might compromise your webserver". Since most sites use layered security and javascript is just additional (because it's often optional) clientside code, I'd wager most security vulnerabilities score low? Looking forward to new insights.

Comment: The article refers to [security vulnerabilities that often occur](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/arshad/publications/ndss2017jslibs.pdf) in outdated JavaScript libraries.

Comment: I think I agree with @Konerak over here. Still, by keeping your dependencies up to date though referencing docs become easier(But it's very subjective)

Answer (score 4):

You can always use the latest jQuery with this url:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
```

Of course you have to be careful as it may break things (especially if there's a major version change).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option for you that does not involve a framework or server side includes

### All pages load your own bootloader library.

So let's assume you have a boorloader.js file and all html files include it. Inside that one file you can insert the following code at the top.

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js";
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
head[0].appendChild(jq);
```

you can abstract much of this to support a lot of different data points but the end result is you asynchronously inject the jQuery library from one file. Update it once and all your HTML is updated too.

Comment: `document.head` is not cross-browser as far as I know.

Comment: thanks, I will update to include a cross browser way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Some form of [template](http://template-toolkit.org/) or [include](http://bignosebird.com/ssi.shtml) system, of which there are many.

Big [frameworks](http://www.catalystframework.org/) tend to come with [template](http://search.metacpan.org/#/showpod/Catalyst%3a%3aView%3a%3aMason) systems, but you don't *have* to use one. You don't even need server side programming if you [preprocess](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/tools/ttree.html).

Answer (score 1):

I generally just use an "opaque" target to a resource *that I control* -- e.g. "jquery.js". This, however has several disadvantages:

1. Can't rely on exact version from CDN (must be a *controlled* resource). For a local Javascript resource this isn't an issue anyway, but it does affect libraries with well-known CDN URLs.
2. All files must use the same version at all times. (e.g. "jquery.js" is "jquery-1.4.1.js"). This has not been a problem for the projects I work on, but it might be an issue as for larger projects.
3. Removal of some self-documentation of version number.

The problems mentioned can be mitigated, but not eliminated, with using a semi-opaque resource, such as "jquery-1.4.js" (note missing revision/bug-fix version; may refer to 1.4.0 or 1.4.1, but not 1.5.x).

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

- Use a common server-side include that will point to the version you want

or

- Point to a local url which you then make resolve to the version you want

Generally speaking, it's not good to update libs with no reason, since the old one does what you want. But generally speaking it's good to wrap interactions with external systems so that you can centrally control them.

Answer (score 0):

It's typically considered to be a bad idea to automatically update frameworks or use a front loader. Basically it means that a third party has a degree of control over your site. If they make a lot of breaking changes in the library, they will automatically get published to your site and now the site that you worked so hard on is broken.

I prefer to put things like JS and CSS in an include or a MasterPage if I'm working in .NET.